# Test two instances of object are equal JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have two objects `A` and `B`. Object `A` is actual result I get during JUnit test. Object `B` is I do a actual end db call and assume as expected review. I need to assert that two object instances `A` and `B` are equal in *value* and not actual object.

We have a method called `assertEquals(obj expected, obj actual)` in JUnit but I don't want that way.

Is there a way or workaround to achieve the same?

Comment: For checking that two objects have the same values I use the following:
**(success)** `assertThat(new Question("title", "id"), is(new Question("title", "id")));`
 **(fail)** `assertThat(new Question("title1", "id1"), is(new Question("title", "id")));`
**With the following imports** `import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;` `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;`

Answer (score 67):

Think about exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.  Do you want to test object identity or verify that the two objects have exactly the same data? From your suggestion of assertEquals I am guessing you want to go field-by-field.

If the objects are shallow you can use

```
assertThat(actual, samePropertyValuesAs(expected));
```

This fails when the object is a composite though.  If you want to walk the entire graph you can use the [sameBeanAs](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) matcher we wrote some time back to address this issue:

```
assertThat(actual, sameBeanAs(expected));
```

If you're using AssertJ then you can also use the built-in functionality like this:

```
assertThat(actual).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expected);
```

Updated in 06/21 - apparently this is deprecated and has been replaced with:

```
assertThat(actual).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expected)
```

One thing you don't want to do it override the `equals` method for this as that might change in the future to accommodate business need.

Comment: Do you know any Hamcrest matcher which we can use?

Comment: samePropertyValuesAs is a built-in Hamcrest matcher.  sameBeanAs is a custom Hamcrest matcher we wrote at Shazam to solve this exact issue

Comment: Use   assertThat(actual).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(expected) if you have object within object.

Comment: Only shazamcrest to-json convertion and comparison helped to compare POJOs with nested objects: `assertThat(actual, sameBeanAs(expected));`

Comment: Can i use objectMapper() to convert my Objects in json and compare? Is this a right way.

Comment: I don't work for shazam anymore, but from what I remember there was no facility to provide a configurable json mapper.  You could always just do it by hand to get the same effect

Comment: since `isEqualToComparingFieldByField` is now deprecated, see  `usingRecursiveComparison`, example: `assertThat(actual).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expected);`

Answer (score 21):

If you want deep equality, you can use Commons Lang3 [`EqualsBuilder#reflectionEquals()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String...)):

```
Assert.assertTrue(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(expected,actual));
```

Comment: This requires you implement equals and hashcode on all levels, which make it not that useful. What is more useful is to perform a deep comparison until the primitive data types.

Comment: Doesn't work for nested objects, though they have the same fields and values, but different instances.

Answer (score 10):

using assertj, you can assert each members of those 2 objects!

e.g. `assertThat(actual).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expected);`

Comment: Can't use this. Hamcrest's assertThat accepts two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`assertEquals()` calls `equals()` on your objects, and there is no way around that. What you can do is to implement something like `public boolean like(MyClass b)` in your class, in which you would compare whatever you want. Then, you could check the result using `assertTrue(a.like(b))`.

Comment: This means polluting your production code with a method purely for test.  Also using assertTrue will give you absolutely no diagnostics on /why/ the test has failed

Comment: I agree on polluting production code with test code, but not on diagnostics why the test failed. If it failed, it failed because actual objects is not "like" expected. If you want more precise info, add a series of asserts for every relevant field .

Comment: The diagnostics you get from this is something like "expected true: got false".  If you modify the test to make better use of assertions you don't need to do any other work.  If you see my answer, all suggestions will produce quality diagnostics not only telling that the test failed but also why

Comment: I wasn't familiar with junit matchers, I'll look into them, sounds like just the thing for this problem.

Comment: Your JUnit world is about to get a whole lot bigger :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the `equals` and for good practise `hashCode` method for your  Class. After that `assertEquals(obj expected, obj actual)` will not check for reference but will use the logic that you have implemented in`equals` method.

Comment: I consider this very bad practise.  You're overriding equals purely to satisfy a test which needs field-by-field comparison.  If the equals contract changes later on then your test will still pass but is not fundamentally broken

Comment: @MrWiggles If we have 2 instance of Some class X then isn't it better to have a decent implementation of `equal` so whenever we need to compare those object we can rely on equals implementation rather then default `equals` implementation inherited from Object class

Comment: If your production code needs the equals then yes, for example if you're putting it inside a Set.  The problem with overriding for a field check like in this instance is that you do a default equals implementation checking each and every field.  If at a later point the equals method should change for a genuine business reason, e.g. compare only on ID, the test that originally needed it is now broken but it won't fail. Also, using equals for this test will give you no diagnostic information about why the objects are different, just that they are

Comment: @MrWiggles I think in that situation we would be better of using matchers

Comment: I don't get why this is bad practice. The equals() method must properly identify two objects as equals. That is going to be the exact same conditions in the "real" application and the unit test. If you need very specialized comparison strategies in your application you're probably doing it very wrong by changing equals() and rather should be using Comparators.

Comment: @Gimby that was my initial thought when Iposted the original solution but may be there are some specialized matchers that allow to achieve the same and if so , then we don't have to change anything in business class. I asked  MrWiggles to post some Hamcrest matcher which achieve the same